# Cannot set Parent property from child class

Tags: php, class, oop

I have view class like this:

```
class View {
    public function __construct() {
    }
    public static function render($name) {
        require 'views/user/header.php';
        require 'views/user/'.$name.'.php';
        require 'views/user/footer.php';
    }
}
```

and I call the view class in controller like this:

```
class Controller {
    function __construct() {
        $this->view = new View();
    }
}
```

and then I set the view property from controller child class, like this:

```
class Index extends Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->view->js = "test";
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->view->render('index/index');
    }
}
```

But when I want to get $this->js from "header.php" which is set at render function on view class, I always get this error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context
```

I was tried to check, Am I in the right class? using this methods in "header.php" file:

```
echo get_class(); // and this method return "View";
```

that means I was on the view class, right?

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined `render()` as a static method, but you are calling it as it was not static.

I would probably benefit from reading this: http://chadminick.com/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html

**P.S.** What you call "view" is just a template.

Comment: Oh...man. I'm not aware if my render function is static. It's work now. thank you very much @tereško.

Comment: link provided isn't valid anymore, article can be found on authors git reop: https://github.com/cythrawll/chadminick.com/blob/master/_posts/2009-09-30-simple-php-template-engine.markdown

Comment: there is also an archive: https://archive.md/CiHhD